# Laravel 9 how to insert select2 multiple in laravel?

Tags: laravel

service_id can be save,select multiple times and save it as foreign keys also

Migration:

```
Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('patient_id');
            $table->foreign('patient_id')->references('id')->on('patients');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('service_id');
            $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->time('time');
            $table->string('status')->default('Pending');
            $table->timestamp('cancelled_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('cancelled_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('cleared_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

if I select 1 service from select option it will saved to sql but when I select 2 or more service its not working.

```
 $formFields = $request->validate([
             'patient_id' => 'required',
             'user_id' => 'required',
            'service_id' => 'required',
             'date' => 'required',
            'time' => 'required',
            // 'status' => 'required'
        ]);
        $reservations = Reservation::create($formFields);

        $successMessage = 'Appointment Booked Successfully!';

        return redirect('/admin/reservations/manage')->with('success', 
        $successMessage);
```

select option of service:

```
<div class="mb-6 col-sm-6">
                    <select class="form-control" name="service_id" id="service_id" multiple>
                        <option value="">--- Select Service ---</option>
                        @foreach (App\Models\Service::orderBy('service_id')->get() as $key => $value)
                            <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->service_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @error ('service_id')
                        <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the service_id as an array.

First change the validator value for service id to:

```php
'service_id.*' => 'required',
```

Then change the create logic to:

```php
$services = $formFields['service_id'];

foreach ($services as $service) {
   $formFields['service_id'] = $service;
   Reservation::create($formFields);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean change the validator value?

Comment: here in your code 

`$request->validate([
             'patient_id' => 'required',
             'user_id' => 'required',
            'service_id' => 'required',
             'date' => 'required',
            'time' => 'required',
            // 'status' => 'required'
        ]);`
change `'service_id' => 'required'`  to `'service_id.*' => 'required'`

Comment: thanks its now working! I'll upvote this! hehehe

Comment: do you know how can I concatenate it?
     $reservations = Reservation::
            selectRaw('patients.*,services.*, reservations.id as id, reservations.*')
            ->join('patients', 'patients.id', '=', 'reservations.patient_id')
            ->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'reservations.service_id')
            ->when($request->date, function ($query, $date) {
                return $query->whereDate('reservations.date', $date);
            })
            ->where('status',$status)
            ->orderBy('date','ASC')
            ->paginate(5);

Comment: `$reservations = Reservation::selectRaw('CONCAT(patients.first_name, " ", patients.last_name) as patient_name, services.*, reservations.id as id, reservations.*')
    ->join('patients', 'patients.id', '=', 'reservations.patient_id')
    ->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'reservations.service_id')
    ->when($request->date, function ($query, $date) {
        return $query->whereDate('reservations.date', $date);
    })
    ->where('status', $status)
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
    ->paginate(5);`

Comment: I get error like this SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: CONCAT